# How to auto select all rows in a JTable and freeze the selection?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I would like to auto select all rows in a JTable and make it impossible to manually change the number of selected rows.

All rows are selected automatically and it should not be possible to alter the selection
[image]

Selecting all rows is pretty straight forward

```
//Auto select all rows in the table
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
        queueTable.selectAll();
     }
});
```

Next step is to remove any possibilities to set focus on the table

```
queueTable.setFocusable(false);
```

Here it stops, how to freeze the selection at this point?

```
queueTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false); // unfortunately this will clear the current selection.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to hardcode that in next way:

```
youeTable.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel(){
    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int arg0, int arg1) {
        super.setSelectionInterval(0, t.getRowCount());
    }
});
```

in that case in your table always be selected rows from `0` to the end of the table.